# Why is an empty array being passed as a parameter to .reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was reading the developer docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

I just wonder why there is an empty array being passed where you would normally indicate the initialvalue?

[image: Image/Code Snippet from MSDN]

Comment: It’s where you would normally indicate the initial value because it *is* a normal initial value in this case. (Although it doesn’t actually matter for array concatenation unless the input array is empty.) Also, it’s a really bad example (quadratic time, replaceable by `.flat()`) and should probably be edited out of MDN.

Answer (score 1):

The only benefit I can see would be if the array you're trying to flatten is empty. In that case, if an initial value is not passed, the `.reduce` will throw an error, because there's nothing to iterate over *and* no initial value to immediately return.

When the array being reduced has no items, the initial value is returned. If there's no initial value, the below error is thrown.

```js
const makeFlat = arr => arr.reduce(
  ( accumulator, currentValue ) => accumulator.concat(currentValue)
);

console.log(makeFlat([['foo']])); // OK

console.log(makeFlat([])); // Error
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value

So, to make the implementation as generic as possible, to work even when one tries to flatten an empty array, pass an initial value of `[]`.

Comment: If the first element is not an Array that would throw too since it would be used as the initialValue, for instance `[1, [2,3], [4,5],6,7]`.

Answer (score 0):

the above code calls concat() on accumulator, concat() only works on arrays and strings, so it is initialized as an empty array.

To know more about [concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)